# How can I use the Excel forecast function to interpolate numbers correctly?

Tags: interpolation, forecast

For an Excel model, I need to interpolate various values between 0 and 1, which can obviously be done with if-statements and what so ever, but I would like to use a neat and robust solution so other people will also understand the file I'm working on.
With the function 'FORECAST', Excel seems to interpolate the values very oddly; some are above 1 and others under 0.

The table I want to interpolate are just numbers, no dates, and looks the following:

[0|1]

[18|1]

[40|0]

[60|0]

So between the values 18 and 40, real interpolation has to happen.

If I use the forecast function, the following output is generated:
[In- and output forecast function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyESY.png)

I think it is very odd that the first few values are higher than 1, since they clearly are between 0 and 18, and the last few values are not equal to 0, since they are between 40 and 80. If you would interpolate the numbers yourself, this should be the case.

Can someone maybe explain what happens, and preferably how I can fix this with an alternative maybe?

The version of Excel I am using is part of Office 365.

Comment: Allright, I got it working myself. 

The problem was the way the Forecast function works; the interpolation is based on a trendline. You can visualize it by plotting the points in a scatterplot and generate a trendline.
To avoid this, the interpolation has to happen between two points only. On the following website [https://exceloffthegrid.com/interpolate-values-using-the-forecast-function/] all the way down they explained how that could be achieved using the Forecast, Index and Match functions in Excel.  They call it 'Inner linear interpolation'.

Thanks for rubberducking internet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I got it working myself.

The problem was the way the Forecast function works; the interpolation is based on a trendline. You can visualize it by plotting the points in a scatterplot and generate a trendline. To avoid this, the interpolation has to happen between two points only. On the [following website](https://exceloffthegrid.com/interpolate-values-using-the-forecast-function/) all the way down they explained how that could be achieved using the Forecast, Index and Match functions in Excel. They call it 'Inner linear interpolation'.

Thanks for rubberducking internet ;-)